# Accessing Outside of a class

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to access a QgraphicsView's Scene outside of a class. I can normally do this when I create a class that is derived from QGraohicsView, but this class is the MainWindow which derives from QMainWIndow and I can have it extend QGraphicsView because there is a conflict when you call the .show() method as the compiler does not know which one to choose.

```
   namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
     }
  class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
       {}
```

So I create a new instance of QgraphicsView and make it public and also Qgraphicsscene and make it public.

Then in the exterior class

```
   extern MainWindow * mainwindow
```

But when I try to access it and I get a undefined reference error.

```
    mainwindow->view->scene()->addItem(item); or
 mainwindow->mainwindow.scene->addItem(item);
```

Neither of them work.
I know its breaking encapsulation but there is no other way around this in this particular case.

** What I am trying to do is access a QgraphicsView's Scene outside of its class?

** MainWindow has public variables

```
        QGraphicsScene *scene;
        QGraphicsView * view;
```

In MainWindow.cpp

```
       scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
       view = new QGraphicsView(scene);
       view.show();
```

Comment: Multiple inheritance. One of the nastinesses in C++.

Comment: Sorry I didnt mean to add c, habbits :(

Comment: Tell us what problem are you trying to solve. Don't ask how to make non-working solutions work - you obviously know by now that they don't work. I don't quite understand what your problem is. Obviously `mainwindow->view` won't work because your `MainWindow` class doesn't have a member by that name. Show real code first!

Comment: I am trying to access a view's scene outide of the class is was created in

Comment: @KubaOber mainwindow has 2 public variable see above edit.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it coherent. In one point you declare `MainWindow` as having no members. In another, you claim that it has public members. Please remove incorrect code and unnecessary comments from your question, and add a self-contained test case that shows your problem. We're talking of a dozen lines of code - you're wasting more time trying to sidestep the problem than tackling it head-on.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. Since `view` in your case was a pointer, you must access its members via `->`, not `.`. But all that is superfluous anyway - you should store everything by value as much as possible and let the compiler worry about making sure the resources are freed when no longer needed. That's why you're using C++, not C, after all.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/simple-view-33508582
#include <QtWidgets>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
  Q_OBJECT
  QGraphicsScene m_scene;
  QWidget m_central;
  QGraphicsView m_view; // must be declared after m_central per C++ semantics
  QGridLayout m_layout;
public:
  MainWindow(QWidget * parent = 0) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    m_layout(&m_central) {
    setCentralWidget(&m_central);
    m_layout.addWidget(&m_view, 0, 0);
    m_view.setScene(&m_scene);
  }
  QGraphicsScene * scene() { return &m_scene; }
  QGraphicsView * view() { return &m_view; }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  MainWindow win;
  win.scene()->addEllipse(0, 0, 10, 10);
  win.show();
  return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

You should also decide whether you need a `QMainWindow` at all. Just because a Qt Creator template uses it, doesn't mean you should blindly use it too. If you're not using `QMainWindow's` docking area functionality, a `QDialog` would be a more sensible base class to use:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/simple-view-33508582
#include <QtWidgets>

class MainWindow : public QDialog {
  Q_OBJECT
  QGraphicsScene m_scene;
  QGraphicsView m_view;
  QGridLayout m_layout;
public:
  MainWindow(QWidget * parent = 0) :
    QDialog(parent),
    m_layout(this) {
    m_layout.addWidget(&m_view, 0, 0);
    m_view.setScene(&m_scene);
  }
  QGraphicsScene * scene() { return &m_scene; }
  QGraphicsView * view() { return &m_view; }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  MainWindow win;
  win.scene()->addEllipse(0, 0, 10, 10);
  win.show();
  return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```